# Wireshark : how to force to drop packets with LUA?

Tags: tcp, lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm am facing to an issue when sniffing on the loopback interface when using a JTAG debug probe, which uses a TCP socket. It completly flood the loopback, and freeze Wireshark after a few seconds.

As a workaround, I have made a dummy LUA dissector for this case (redlink-server protocol). Wireshark is no longer freezing, but it produces like 8Gb of packets in a few minutes...
(the plugin consists in an empty dissector function, add register this dissector for TCP port 3490)

Is there a simple way to delete those packets from dump file not to overflow my RAM ?

Tanks by advance

Thomas.

Comment: Are you trying to capture the JTAG debug probe traffic or are you trying to exclude it?  Assuming you're trying to exclude it, you can add a capture filter to either only capture the traffic you're interested in, or you can add a capture filter to specifically exclude the JTAG traffic.  For example, to exclude traffic on port 3490, you'd use `not tcp port 3490`.  Refer to [pcap-filter](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) for more information on capture filters.

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard I wan't to exclude trafic from TCP 3490. Using a filter, only filter what is displayed on wireshark, isn't it ? I'm affraid the frames are still captured, maybe I'm wrong. Wireshark will take 24G of RAM after 5 minutes of capture (33,000,000 TCP packets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a capture filter, not a display filter, to avoid capturing the traffic.  In your case, the capture filter to exclude the unwanted traffic would be `not tcp port 3490`.

Refer to [pcap-filter](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) for more information on capture filters, as well as the Wireshark User Guide, [Section 4.10. Filtering while capturing](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCapCaptureFilterSection.html).

Comment: Thanks, I have confused display filter and capture filter ... My bad.
Doing `not tcp port 3490` did the trick. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome.  Note that when working with capture filters, there can sometimes be room for optimization.  For example, the filter I provided produces 20 BPF instructions because it checks for both IPv4 or IPv6 packets, and it checks both source and destination ports.  But if you know IPv6 isn't applicable, and you know only the destination port matters, you can reduce the number of BPF instructions from 20 to 11 by using this filter instead: `ip and not tcp dst port 3490`.  Use Wireshark's *"Compile BPFs"* button to view the generated instructions or use `dumpcap` with the `-d` option.

Comment: Thanks for the additional infos. Would be nice also if I could add directly this filter into a LUA plugin.